# Worksheet object not callable OpenpyXL error

Tags: python, arrays, function, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a function that loads an excel sheet row into an array but keep on running into this error.

Code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
oldworkbook = load_workbook(filename="111.xlsx")
oldsheet=oldworkbook.active
def rowtoArray(startRow,oldsheet):
    sheet=oldsheet
    arr = []
    x = 0
    ***while(oldsheet(row=startRow, column=x).value):
        arr.append(oldsheet(row=startRow, column=x).value)***

    return arr
```

Error:

> `TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable`

I am a bit new to Openpyxl. I tried passing in 'sheet' / oldsheet as a parameter but still get the same error, I am not getting this error if I run the exact same code out of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the code is in the while loop condition. The correct syntax for accessing a cell value in openpyxl is sheet.cell(row=startRow, column=x).value`.
So try this:

```
while(sheet.cell(row=startRow, column=x).value):
    arr.append(sheet.cell(row=startRow, column=x).value)
```

Comment: Happy to hear that